# Class Link works for what I am doing, however, it changes styling of all links on site

Tags: css

I have a site in Wordpress where I am inserting a block with html.

This is the inserted html code:

```
<div class=“options-bar”>

<a href="https://total-speed-customs.myshopify.com/?" class=“options-bar-btn”>FUEL INJECTORS</a>
<a href="https://total-speed-customs.myshopify.com/collections/ignition" class=“options-bar-btn”>IGNITIONS</a>
<a href="https://total-speed-customs.myshopify.com/?" class=“options-bar-btn”>BOLTS</a>
<a href="https://total-speed-customs.myshopify.com/collections/e85-fuel" class=“options-bar-btn”>ELECTRONICS</a>
<a href="https://total-speed-customs.myshopify.com/collections/trailer-parts" class=“options-bar-btn”>WINCHES</a>
```

HITCHES

```
</div>
```

This is in the theme.css stylesheet at the very bottom:

```
.options-bar {
text-align: center;
```

}

```
.options-bar-btn, a { display: inline-block; 
color: white !important;
text-decoration: none; 
background: black !important; 
padding: 10px 20px; 
margin: 0px 5px; 
border-radius: 6px;  
text-align: center;
font-size: 22px;
```

}

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px)  {

.options-bar-btn, a { display: inline-block; 
color: white !important;
text-decoration: none; 
background: black !important; 
padding: 3px 3px; 
margin: 0px 1px; 
border-radius: 3px;  
text-align: center;
font-size: 10px;
```

}

}

It works for the inserted block html, but it also changes the styling of links sitewide. I've enclosed a link to the site in progress to show the row of buttons working correctly, but the top nav has the same styling, which needs to just be transparent for the logo and the main nav.

What I'm missing?

https://total-speed-customs.myshopify.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression `.options-bar-btn, a {...}` means the following: set the following styles to all elements that have class **options-bar-btn** and to all tags **a** as well.

The comma in your code is a separator between *two* rules.

When you need to set a rule for an element that is a child of an element with class **options-bar**:

```
.options-bar a {
   color: white !important;
}
```

This will select all **a** tags inside the elements with class **options-bar**.

If you want to change a style of all the links with class **options-bar-btn**:

```
a[class*="options-bar-btn"] {
    color: white !important;
}
```

This will select all tags **a** then filter elements that has **options-bar-btn** class set.

Comment: @bluewater2222: Be sure to mark Kirill's answer as accepted when you get a chance by clicking the checkmark next to it. If you feel so compelled, I also recommend upvoting it, given that you found it so useful.